# Xlookup and pull result based on cell length (there's two results) or pull one of two results based on cell length

Tags: excel, excel-formula

In my example I'm trying to pull the result for xlookup based on the length of the cell, shown below there are two cells, one length is 10 characters, the other 8. Is it possible to vlookup and pull the result based on the desired length?

Formula: `=TEXTJOIN(",",TRUE,UNIQUE(FILTER('Main Report'!$L:$L,ISNUMBER(MATCH('Main Report'!$AB:$AB,$AG34,0)),"")))`

(This formula pulls both results right now)
My matching Manufacturer ID is on AG

[image: Data Source]

[image: Results]

Comment: Wrap it with `if(len()>8`?

Comment: It's a good idea, but I cannot figure out how to get that to show me the result. This will only say if yes or no to length = 8, maybe i'm not doing it correctly.

=IF(LEN(XLOOKUP(AG34,'Main Report'!AB:AB,'Main Report'!S:S))<8,"","")

Comment: Instead of "", you need to put the formula there. And don't you want >8 since one is 10 and other 8.